# android Cannot create files in /data with root privilege

Tags: android, c++, linux

I am trying to build a executable file `smtm` running on android to create a file in /data folder with root privilege, but my codes keeps returning null,
Here is my code

```
void change_uid() {
    cout << "before getuid : " << getuid() << ", getgid : " << getgid() << endl;
    cout << "setgroups(0, NULL) : " << setgroups(0, NULL) << ", setgid(0) : " << setgid(0) << ", setuid(0) : "
            << setuid(0) << endl;
    cout << "after getuid : " << getuid() << ", getgid : " << getgid() << endl;
}


void test_write_data() {
    FILE *fd = fopen("/data/smtm.txt", "a+");
    if (NULL != fd) {
        int count = fprintf(fd, "%s", "write something");
        cout <<"fprintf count == " << count << endl;
        int result = fclose(fd);
        cout <<"fclose result == " << result << endl;
        fd = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("fd == null\n");
    }
}


int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[]) {
    change_uid();
    cout << "***step test_write_data*" << endl;
    test_write_data();
}
```

the file smtm's location and output are :

[image]

I don't know why i cannot create a file even after set uid and gid as zero, although it work fine after calling su.

Comment: You should tag this as c++ and not c as your example code is c++

Comment: anybody?
i think that's selinux issue, but i haven't found a way to change a process's context. i wonder how su does that